# Ionic Vue 3 - Data does not update in Vue Dev Tools

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ionic-framework, ionic2, vuejs3

Reactive and Ref data does not update in Vue Dev Tools when changes are made in input field (binded with v-model) in form. I can see the updated data when I click on some other component and then go to previous component in dev tools.

Is this reactivity issue? How?

Answer (score 1):

Got same problem, in my case, just using refresh button, helped[image]